# ¿Qué es el tercer parámetro de os.execl de python?

Tags: python

El siguiente código permite una elevación de privilegios por medio de SUID:

```
python -c 'import os; os.execl("/bin/sh","sh", "-p")'
```

Tengo claro que el primer parámetro de os.execl hace una llamada a la shell sh, el segundo parámetro es el valor que se introduce en el prompt de la nueva shell, pero el tercer parámetro que es "-p" no entiendo que hace, se que hace algo ya que cuando es diferente de "p" no se hace la elevación de privilegios, es decir, no me devuelve una shell con privilegios de root. ¿Qué es el tercer parámetro?¿Que valores se pueden introducir?

Comment: En serio? nadie? RTFM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

En la documentación de `os.execl` se puede ver que la función acepta varios argumentos

```
os.execl(path, arg0, arg1, ...)
```

Es decir, `os.execl(path, *arg)` y esos argumentos afectan al programa que `os.execl` va a ejecutar, pero son argumentos propios de ese programa, no de `os.execl` por lo que `-p` es una opción de `sh` y no un argumento de la función `os.execl`

La documentación de las posibles opciones/argumentos la puedes encontrar [aquí](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Invoking-Bash). Menciona que `-p` es para activar el modo privilegiado y enlista todas las opciones disponibles.

Comment: Acabo de hacer la prueba y efectivamente tienes razón, es un parámetro propio de `/bin/sh` y no de `os.execl`. Gracias.

Comment: No hay de que, saludos!